# What state does running sagaMiddleware.run(...) change?

Tags: redux-saga

Here is my store:

```
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
...
export const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();    
...
const enhancers: StoreEnhancer[] = [
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
    applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history))
];
...
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSagas);
```

Running `sagaMiddleware.run(rootSagas)` does not return any value but effects the application. I am wondering where this side effect is stored. `sagaMiddleware` is a constant, so it can't be stored in that object.

I am guessing that as `sagaMiddleware` is applied as an enhanced to store, state related to `sagaMiddleware` is stored there. But I am unsure about this.

- Are side effects from `sagaMiddleware.run(...)` stored in the store object or somewhere else?
- If I would want to learn more about the workings of `sagaMiddleware`, where should I look?

Answer (score 0):

> What state does running sagaMiddleware.run(…) change?

No state at all, they shouldn't. As per docs

> Sagas are implemented as **Generator functions** that yield objects to
>   the redux-saga middleware

you would need a basic understanding of how they work. Please read the tutorial and the docs about them

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html#

> Are side effects from sagaMiddleware.run(...) stored in the store
>   object or somewhere else?

No

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

> If I would want to learn more about the workings of sagaMiddleware,
>   where should I look?

At the source code ;) https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga